# neo4j : Unable to get a routing table for database 'fabric.xxx' because this database does not exist

Tags: neo4j

hope you are doing well,
Here is my problem :-

when i setup neo4j in centos everything was working as excepted but when i started to setup fabric shard it was working fine but when i run this query on fabric master it

:use newfabric.db_name;

it show me error like :-

```
 **"Unable to get a routing table for database 'newfabric.db_name' because this database does not exist"**
```

but this database exists on that machine.

Please tell me what to do now...i am stuck here
Here is details from fabric machine enter code here`:-

OS : centos 7
Neo version: Neo4j 4.2

i have made these changes on fabric machine

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
dbms.backup.listen_address=0.0.0.0:6362
dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.default_advertised_address=server_public_ip

dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=DISABLED
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687
dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=server_public_ip:7687

# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
#dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=server_public_ip:7474

dbms.mode=SINGLE
fabric.database.name=newfabric
fabric.routing.servers=server_public_ip:7687

# January's shard
fabric.graph.0.name=january2020
fabric.graph.0.uri=neo4j://server_public_ip:port
fabric.graph.0.database=db_name

# february's shard
fabric.graph.1.name=february2020
fabric.graph.1.uri=neo4j://server_public_ip:port
fabric.graph.1.database=db_name
```

on shard machines i have only opened this line
dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=server_public_ip:7687

Please help me on same ...!!!
Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0):

try "newfabric.january2020" in the query.

Comment: thanks a lot #RaviKiran 

but it was not issue of configuration / Query..it was issue of enterprise version which was resolved after taking help from neo4j itself...